# autoloading facebook SDK using psr-4

Tags: php, json, composer-php, facebook-php-sdk

I've installed the Facebook PHP SDK using composer, however once the dependencies were installed, i noticed in the vendor/facebook directory there is another composer.json file. Does this need to be run as well? Now that the Facebook dependency has been installed, how can i refer to use it?

Any advice of any kind would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about that `composer.json` file.

Similar to `composer.json` in *your* project, `facebook/php-sdk-v4` uses its own `composer.json` to define its development and non-development dependencies.

When you run

```
$ composer install
```

in the root of your project, `composer` resolves not only the dependencies you specified in your root `composer.json`, but furthermore the non-development dependencies of your dependencies (if they have any), using the respective `composer.json` files in these packages.

After it has downloaded all required dependencies, it automatically prepares autoloading, so all you need to do to use any of your dependencies is to require `vendor/autoload.php`.

For reference, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading.